# SignalR progress bar not resumed when i navigate to other page and come back

Tags: signalr, progress-bar

I am using signalR in a web form application(not MVC, MVVM) to show the progress bar on a page which shows progress percentage, my problem is when i navigate to other page and come back on previous page, the progress bar restarts. i want it to resume from where i left it. below is my signalR hub code-

```
public void CallLongOperation()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x <= count; x++)
        {
            // delay the process for see things clearly
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            if (x == 20)
                msg = "Loading Application Settings...";

            else if (x == 40)
                msg = "Applying Application Settings...";

            else if (x == 60)
                msg = "Loading User Settings...";

            else if (x == 80)
                msg = "Applying User Settings...";

            else if (x == 100)
                msg = "Process Completed!...";

            // call client-side SendMethod method
            Clients.Caller.sendMessage(string.Format
                    (msg + " {0}% of {1}%", x, count), x);


        }


    }
```

and i am calling this function in javascript in my aspx page.

```js
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

            // initialize progress bar
            $("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: 0 });

            // initialize the connection to the server
            var progressNotifier = $.connection.progressHub

            // client-side sendMessage function that will be called from the server-side
            progressNotifier.client.sendMessage = function (message) {
                // update progress

                UpdateProgress(message);
            };

            // establish the connection to the server and start server-side operation
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                // call the method CallLongOperation defined in the Hub
                progressNotifier.server.callLongOperation();
            });

        });

        function UpdateProgress(message) {
            // get result div
            var result = $("#result");
            // set message
            result.html(message);
            // get progress bar
            var value = $("#progressbar").progressbar("option", "value");
            // update progress bar
            $("#progressbar").progressbar("value", value + 1);

        }

    </script>
```

```html
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <div style="width: 30%; margin: 0 auto;">
            <div id="result" style="font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 0.9em; color: darkgray; margin-top: 230px; padding-bottom: 5px">
                Initializing and Preparing...
            </div>

            <div id="progressbar" style="width: 300px; height: 15px"></div>
            <br />
        </div>
        <a href="Default.aspx" target="_self">Go Home</a>
    </form>



</body>
```

please suggest the solution.

Comment: Did my answer help or no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to explain the problem as simply as possible.

This code :

```
        // establish the connection to the server and start server-side operation
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            // call the method CallLongOperation defined in the Hub
            progressNotifier.server.callLongOperation();
        });
```

Is executing your method on the server `public void CallLongOperation()` every time the page is reloaded and the connection to the hub is re-established. You will need to either :

1. Architect your webpages like a SPA (single page app) so they don't need to reload.
2. Store the value in a static `ConcurrentDictionary` *per user* so that the server can "remember" the state of the progress bar per User.

As I see it, those are your only 2 options without some major rearchitecture.